# Configuring Logging for multiple projects in solution

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I am using enterprise library logging block 5.0. My solution has over 20 projects, most of them are class libraries. When configuring the enterprise library, do I need to add app.config in all the projects and create logging related sections in each of the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to duplicate logging settings in all projects. You can create it once, store it in a single file or database and then use non-default configuration sources to share as described in Scenarios 2 and 3 of [Developer's Guide. Appendix D - Enterprise Library Configuration Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953193%28PandP.50%29.aspx)